# Linking back-end (MongoDB via Mongoose, on Express server in Node.js) to front-end (Bootstrap or Foundation) in a reactive way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, user-interface, frontend

Is it possible to link:

- a back-end made with a MongoDB database, accessible with Mongoose in a server made in Node.js with Express;
- a front-end made with Bootstrap or Foundation, that would be reactive to the queries to the database, for example: if I want to display data (images, links, texts) that comes from the database but, depending the query and the results given from the database, can have 3, 10 or 15 entries... I think of making a page that would look like Digg.com but with a number of articles displayed that would depend of what my database has at the moment the query is made, but still appear in a beautiful way on the webpage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. Nothing would prohibit you from using these technologies together that you've listed.

Comment: p.s. Asking more detailed questions about implementation might yield more useful results.